# Drawing Issue in Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on Win32 application. All drawing is done in WM_PAINT. It is working fine. i added one more functionality in it. When i click on button than Command prompt is executed. This i can done using WinExec. Now when i move Cmd.exe than in background drawing is not done.
I update the code with CreateProcess than also the same thing is happened. Can anyone please help me whats wrong with this code. Is it because when i focus on This window than focus is losed and drawing is not done.

Code

```
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );          
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

TCHAR  wchCmdPath[MAX_PATH];
memset(wchCmdPath,_T('\0'),MAX_PATH);
GetSystemDirectory(wchCmdPath,MAX_PATH);
wcscat(wchCmdPath,_T("\\cmd.exe"));
// Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    wchCmdPath,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
) 
{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}



// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );


        InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be much easier to detect the problem if you posted the relevant portions of your code.

Answer (score 4):

It may be because `WinExec` returns when the spawned executable calls `GetMessage` or until a timeout is specified (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx ).

This means that until this happens, your program is stuck at this line and is therefore not processing messages (including `WM_PAINT`).  `CreateProcess` doesn't have this problem, but were you waiting on it at all?

Comment: Using  WaitForSingleObject (infinite) i had dont it but when i move command window n number of times than n number of command window appears on screen. :) if i use it at some milliseconds 2000 than problem remains the same

Comment: See my answer - while waiting your application needs to process the messages and paint if it is requested to do so. Nobody else will be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies outside of the code you have posted. Your InvalidateRect / UpdateWindow will paint the window once after the child process is spawned, but it will not handle redrawing as you move it later.

What you need to solve the "Now when i move Cmd.exe than in background drawing is not done" issue is to think about what are you doing while you are waiting for the process. While waiting for the process, you still need to process incoming messages (at least the `WM_PAINT` one).

You cannot use WaitForSingleObject to wait for the process, you need to use some function which will let you handle messages as well, like MsgWaitForMultipleObjects - it is your application who needs to repaint the window each time WM_PAINT is sent, nobody will do it for you.

Another approach is not to wait for the process at all, but implement handling its result in an event-driven fashion, right in the main message loop (what you do now can be viewed as a "modal" process, perhaps you can rethink your application to make it "modeless").

Comment: I Suma, Thanks for your reply.                                 Actually i am new for win32 programming. i worked on MFC, ATL and COM only. What i understand is that instead of using WaitForSingleObject use MsgWaitForMultipleObject.                   MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS-1,&pi.hProcess,TRUE,2000,QS_ALLEVENTS);                             On WM_PAINT all drawing logic is done.  I dont understand your Another approach. Can you please explain it to me in detail. Again Thanks.

Comment: For the event driven approach your message loop (do you have one?) needs to use MsgWaitForMultipleObject so that it can also intercept the process result. As for event-driven programming as a style, just google it - be aware if requires a bit different way of thinking about program flow.

Comment: Also, why MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS-1, ? This is plain wrong - just use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1 as you are testing just one object.